# How to Handle linux file upload dialogue using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating one web application. In that, I have to Automate one module which is file upload. When selenium clicks on upload button of application, in that case window which consist all the file displays. So there I want to go to specific folder , So I can select required file. By default there is no search button is coming in the upload dialogue, if it will be there then I can directly send the file path using sendKeys().

Any way to handle this situation or anyone has faced same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use below logic to upload file

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='sql-file-upload'][type='file']")).sendKeys("/home/test/updaloadThis.jpg");
```

You can directly send the file absolute path to file upload locator.

Comment: What is happening if you do like that ? Is that locator correct ? Post your html code for that file upload operation.

Comment: <input id="sql-file-upload" class="upload" type="file" name="attachments"> this is the html code for that file upload. I think we can use sendKeys only when search option is visible.

Comment: try with this By.cssSelector("input[id='sql-file-upload'][type='file']"). (I've updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use xdotool.
I have version 3.20160805.1 which is working like a charm.

xdotool --version
xdotool version 3.20160805.1

xdotool supports any browser to upload files as is (no need to convert to any type).
I have used xdotool to upload pdf, zip, jpg, txt, doc, xlsx etc., file types.

Refer [link](https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/xdotool/) to install xdotool in Ubuntu.